# Прсто не понимаю откуда такой результат. Может кто объяснит как это работает, кажется я не понимаю что-то очевидное но вот что

Tags: c, cs50, локальные-переменные

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
int dollars;
int coins1;
int quarter = 25;
int dime = 10;
int nickel = 5;
int penny = 1;


do
{
    dollars = get_float("Введите сумму\n");
}
while(dollars <= 1);

int cents = round(dollars * 100);

for (int coins = 0 ; cents > 0; coins++)
{
    if(cents >= 25)
    {
        cents = (cents - quarter);
    }
    else if(cents >= 10)
    {
        cents = (cents - dime);
    }
    else if(cents >= 5)
    {
        cents = (cents - nickel);
    }
    else if(cents >= 1)
    {
        cents = (cents - penny);
    }
    else
    {
        coins1 = coins;
    }
}
printf("%i\n", coins1);
}
```

Comment: покажите результат и расскажите точнее что непонятно

Comment: `int dollars; ... dollars = get_float("Введите сумму\n");` Хотите впихнуть невпихуемое?

Comment: @wololo Спасибо, это и вовсе не заметил. Но после изменения float dollars; Результат отсался такой же. А вообще интересно как оно работало вообще.

Comment: @AlexGlebe  На выходе результат 32766 а такого и в помине быть не должно. Эта программа должна считать какое минимальное колличество монет мы можем дать пользоваетелю. А не понятно как получилось то что получилось. В моем понимании она должна делать именно то что в условии задачи.

Comment: Вы забыли нуль по умолчанию присвоить `float coins1 = 0; .. printf("%f\n", coins1);` Но скорее всего вы хотели увидет количество монет , тогда `printf("%i\n", coins);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А вы уверены, что обязательно выскочите в ветвь, в которой выполняется  `coins1 = coins;`?

А если подумать?

Цикл работает, пока `cents > 0`. А пока это так - хода в последний `else` нет. А как только `cents` становится равной нулю, выполняется выход из цикла, и `coins1` так и остается неинициализированной локальной переменной.

Кстати, тот же VC++ выдает соответствующее предупреждение - о потенциально неинициализированной переменной.

И вообще, я бы писал так:

```
int coins(int cents)
{
    const int val[] = { 25, 10, 5, 1 };
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(val)/sizeof(val[0]); ++i)
    {
        cnt += cents/val[i];
        cents %= val[i];
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, с переменной разобрался. Но даже в этом случае программа работает не так как должна. Результат получается не тот что нужен, как я это вижу на данный момент я ввожу значение 6.1 после этого это чистло с помощью round округляется до целых чисел и дальше запускается цикл for который в свою очередь разложен на ветви 25, 10, 5, 1 если число которе получилось после округления  >=  25 от него отнимается 25 когда станет меньше будет работать следующая ветвь отнимать уже минус 10 и так далее 5 и 1 (при каждой операции - coins++) в конце концов условие цикла будет фолс.Громите мою логику

Comment: А что громить? Все работает верно - если верно написать. 6.10 - это 24 по 25 центов + 10 центов. Всего 25 монет. Получите и распишитесь: https://ideone.com/1DCjuy Просто вынес `coins` за цикл, а потом его вывел. Что не так? Конечно, я бы не писал настолько неэффективно, но это уже дело десятое...

Comment: Кстати, забавно у вас - используете все эти quarter, dime - но в сравнении пишете числа. Тогда уж или везде числа пишите, или везде имена...

Comment: coins за цикл я вынес, программа рбаотает, но вот только получаю я 6.10
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23

Comment: Я не знаю, как вы исправили свою программу и что написали не так, я не телепат и не имею хрустального шара увидеть то, что вы не показываете. Как сделать правильно, я указал - см. ссылку, там работающий код. И вообще, лично я бы написал не так - см. в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо вам. Во всем разобрался. А так как пишите вы мне писать еще не скоро.

Comment: Гораздо быстрее, чем вам сейчас кажется :)